# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST When Insert data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I just tried to insert data using ajax json but I'm getting a error like this. I checked in the controller, route and model. There's nothing wrong with how to set it up. Please help.

For View Blade

```
  function add() {
        save_method = 'add';
        $('#form_jabatan')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
        $('[name="kode"]').prop("readonly", false);
    }
    function save() {
        var url = "";
        if (save_method === 'add') {
            url = "<?php echo url('/simpanjabatan') ?>";
        } else {
            url = "<?php echo url('/simpanjabatan') ?>";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form_jabatan').serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.errors) {
                    jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
                        jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                        jQuery('.alert-danger').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
                    });
                } else {
                    alert(data.status);
                    $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                    reloadpage();
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("Error json " + error);
                json = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
                $.each(json.errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('.alert-danger').show("");
                    $('.alert-danger').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="content-heading">Form Detail Jabatan</h2>
    <!-- Dynamic Table Full -->
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-header block-header-default">
            <h3 class="block-title">DATA TABLE Detail Jabatan</h3>
        </div>
        <div class=" block-content block-content-full table-responsive">
            <button type="button" onclick="add();" class="btn btn-primary mr-5 mb-5" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-plus mr-5"></i>Kelola Jabatan
            </button>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="example" class=" table  table-striped js-dataTable-full-pagination ">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th >ID JABATAN</th>
                        <th >JENIS JABATAN</th>
                        <th >GAJI_POKOK</th>
                        <th >Aksi</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- DataTables functionality is initialized with .js-dataTable-full-pagination class in js/pages/be_tables_datatables.min.js which was auto compiled from _es6/pages/be_tables_datatables.js -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Page Content -->
<!-- From Right Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-fromright"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-fromright" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="block block-themed block-transparent">
                <div class="block-header bg-primary-dark">
                    <h3 class="block-title">FORM Detail Jabatan</h3>
                    <div class="block-options">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-block-option" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="si si-close"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form">
                    <form action="#" id="form_jabatan" class="form-horizontal">

                        <input name="_token" type="hidden" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {{--<label type="hidden" class="control-label col-md-3">Kode</label>--}}
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <input name="kode" type="hidden" class="form-control" type="text"
                                           placeholder="Kode">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Jenis Jabatan</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="jabatan" name="jabatan">
                                        <option value="0">Silahkan Pilih</option>
                                        <option value="1">Ka Mantri</option>
                                        <option value="1">Ka Mantri(baru)</option>
                                        <option value="2">Kasir</option>
                                        <option value="2">Staff Admin</option>
                                        <option value="2">Mantri</option>
                                        <option value="2">Mantri(Baru)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="val-name">Gaji Pokok</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gaji" name="gaji"
                                           placeholder="Masukan gaji...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save();" class="btn btn-primary">Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END From Right Modal -->
```

For Controller

```
 public function simpanjabatan(Request $req)
{
    $obj = new DetailJabatanModel();
    $obj->id_jabatan = $req->input('kode');
    $obj->jabatan = $req->input('jabatan');
    $obj->gaji_pokok = $req->input('gaji');
    $simpan = $obj->save();
    if ($simpan == 1) {
        $status = "Tersmpan";
    } else {
        $status = "Gagal";
    }
    echo json_encode(array("status" => $status));
}
```

for route

```
Route::post('/simpanjabatan', 'FormJabatanController@simpanjabatan');
```

I want to insert with json but I got erorr:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Where is the `return` statement after you have saved this object?  What are you returning back to ajax?  Or is this just a test with an echo from this function?

Comment: I run your code from my side. There is no error about which one you are getting. Would you please clear your route cache? `php artisan route: cache`

Comment: `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Have you watched the call in your dev tools network traffic to see what type of method it is using

Comment: @cfkane In my case `Request Method: POST`

Comment: i check in network xhr and i got this 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `detail_jabatan` (`id_jabatan`, `jabatan`, `gaji_pokok`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Mantri, 500000, 2019-10-14 02:09:03, 2019-10-14 02:09:03))"